# rcpp equivalent of help(function)

Tags: r, rcpp

In [r](/questions/tagged/r) it's easy to find help:

```
?matrix
# or
help(matrix)
```

Is there an equivalent for [rcpp](/questions/tagged/rcpp)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with an `Rcpp` prompt. What help are you looking for? I mean, there are vignettes at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html, lots of docs at http://www.rcpp.org/, Dirk's discussion about the concept at http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html, and the Advanced R chapter at http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html.

Comment: @r2evans I am looking for any kind of equivalent to ```?function``` - it is always great to see what a function take and what value it provides. I am largely out of my comfort zone in```Rcpp``` but an equivalent of ```?``` would be great. As is I am putting periods after my classes trying to figure out which method may be helpful

Comment: Closest probably is the API documentation that describes the function and provides example I wrote awhile back. Just be ready to use `CNTRL`/`CMD` + `F`: https://github.com/coatless/rcpp-api/blob/master/rcpp-api-docs.Rmd

Comment: I think I understand. Just like regular R functions can be documented or not, similar functions written in C++ with `Rcpp` bindings may be documented or not. If it is documented (in a [roxygen-like way](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/roxygen2.html)), then `?function` should still work. In my experience, though, many Rcpp-based functions are not directly exported, relying on the R wrappers for some control or shaping. **Bottom line**: I think your access to function help is exactly the same ... but some authors make less user-documentation for their C++-based code.

Comment: Which Rcpp function would you expect documentation like this? Generally the `help` function is meant for functions exported to R. Other forms of documentation are used for the C++ side.

Comment: @coatless I like the link. If you make it an answer and also refer to this: http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/html/Matrix_8h_source.html I would accept.

Comment: @RalfStubner I am looking for all of it - ```?something``` is so ingrained that I mistakenly assumed it was a thing for other languages. I think you are right that I just need to use other forms of documentation

Comment: @Cole With all due respect that is a non-starter.   Why do you think we have nine vignettes?  A custom search engine shortcut and/or a link to the Doxygen docs are probably the best you can do. And  _actual functions_ like `cppFunction()` do of course have help.